# Given a line, find the point perpendicular to that line that passes through (A2, B2)

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

[image]
Hello! I'm struggling to figure out how to find $(\text A_1, \text B_1)$ in this diagram. I know I can use the dot product to find it somehow since they are orthogonal, just can't figure out how. I know the values of all the other points. Any hints?

Comment: Try if lines $a\perp b\implies m_a m_b=-1$ with the slopes and the point slope formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the orthogonal projection of $(A_2, B_2)$ onto the red line.  Calculate the unit normal vector to the red line.  You have the vector

$$ V = (V_x, V_y) = (x_2 - x_1, y_2 - y_1) $$

Pointing along the red line.

A unit normal (perpendicular) vector is

$$ N = \dfrac{(-V_y, V_x) }{\sqrt{ V_x^2 + V_y^2} } $$

Now the projection of $P = (A_2, B_2)$ onto the red line is $Q = (A_1, B_1)$ where

$$\boxed{Q = (x_1, y_1) + (I - N N^T) (P - (x_1, y_1) )} $$

The matrix $(I - {NN}^T) $ is the orthogonal projection matrix.

As an example suppose $(x_1,y_1) = (1, 1)$ and $(x_2, y_2) = (7, 8) $, and suppose $P = (A_2, B_2) = (6 ,1) $, then

$ N = \dfrac{ ( -7, 6) }{\sqrt{ 85 }} $

So

$(I - {NN}^T) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 \\ 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} - \dfrac{1}{85} \begin{bmatrix} 49 && -42 \\ -42 && 36 \end{bmatrix} =\dfrac{1}{85} \begin{bmatrix} 36 && 42 \\ 42 && 49 \end{bmatrix} $

Therefore,

$ Q = (A_1, B_1) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} + \dfrac{1}{85} \begin{bmatrix} 36 && 42 \\ 42 && 49 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = \dfrac{1}{85} \begin{bmatrix} 265 \\ 295 \end{bmatrix} $

Hence,

$$Q = (\dfrac{265}{85}, \dfrac{295}{85} ) $$

[image]